# Fabric Crashlytics: Upload-Symbols behind proxy (with Fastlane)

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, fastlane, google-fabric

In FastLane, I have a module that uploads the symbols to Crashlytics for my iOS project, using the Fabric.app/upload-symbols script.
When connected to the internet, this script works beautifully.

But this build server can only reach the internet through a proxy server.

Anyone know how I can pass this script proxy settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todd from Fabric here. To support a blocked traffic device, just whitelist the following domains on ports 80 and 443:*.fabric.io*.crashlytics.com

It's important to note that we don't support IP whitelisting because we use AWS and our IPs change very often. If you're using domains as a way of obtaining IP addresses, please be aware that the IP addresses will change very frequently - potentially every 24 hours.

Comment: Hi Todd, thank you for the suggestion. So there is no way to pass a proxy to the script? I

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue and been searching for a solution for days. Is there a way to pass proxy parameters to upload-symbols; it seems to ignore both network settings and environment variables.